# will hasher.combine(self) cause trouble while using collections?

Tags: arrays, swift, hashable

Can using this implementation of `hash(into:)` cause problems, especially using collections and arrays?:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher){
    hasher.combine(self)
}
```

Comment: Why would you hash `self`? The idea is to hash your properties together to create a Hashable's hash value. Can you provide some context to show why this would be a thing to do?

Comment: If the computer knew what hashing `self` would mean, there'd be no purpose to the `hash(into:)` method. Indeed, the method exists to define what exactly is means to hash `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm farily certain that `hasher.combine(self)` would either not compile or result in an infinite loop.

When `hasher.combine()` sees the type that it is given, it is going to look for that objects `hash(into:)` function, which will call `hasher.combine()` with the same type, and so on and so forth.

What you should do is

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(property1)
    hasher.combine(prop2)
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //until you have written a line to combine every property you want to hash
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: On Xcode Version 11.3 and swift 5, it did compile, but now that you explained how it works, I won't be using it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Hasher implementation leads to an error :

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeec79fe8)

This is a default way to conform a type to `Hashable` protocol

```
/// A point in an x-y coordinate system.
struct GridPoint {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

extension GridPoint: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: GridPoint, rhs: GridPoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(x)
        hasher.combine(y)
    }
}
```